# Changing zoom level of child window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using `window.open()` to open a new window. The new window shows a video in it. Problem is that when the user changes the zoom level on the parent window, the child window inherits the same zoom level, and the video isn't properly shown in the new window. Is there anyway to restrict the new window to use same zoom level.

Couple of approaches I tried (and which didn't work):

1. I tried setting the zoom level using `body.style.zoom = '100%'` but it's not cross browser supported, and it takes whatever is the zoom level set by browser as 100%. So if user sets browser zoom level to be 200%, this code, simply sets zoom level to be 200% and effectively does nothing.
2. I tried CSS transform property, but it also fails because of same reasons as mentioned for above point.

Any other solution you would recommend?

Comment: I just ran `window.open('about:blank').document.body.textContent = 'Zoomit'` and changing zoom here does not affect the new tab and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable or change the zoom in basically all browsers. Other things you can try:

- You can set the `video` element to `width: 100%; height: 100%`. The video and the player won't scale but text will.
- If you can use newer CSS technology, you can use viewport-based sizing; see https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/